# sql aggregations

Tags: sql, sql-server

any ideas why this doesn't work?

```
select [column_name_2], max(count(distinct([column_name_1])))
from [table_name]
group by [column_name_2]
```

but it works if done like this

```
select [column_name_2], count(distinct([column_name_1])) as [x]
into #temp_table
from [table_name]
group by [column_name_2]

select max(x)
from #temp_table
```

Comment: Is this SQL Server?

Comment: @JBrooks yes it is

Comment: It doesn't work because nested aggregation functions are not allowed in SQL (although Oracle does extend the language to support them).

Answer (score 1):

Well, that's just the way SQL (the language) is defined to work.  When you use `GROUP BY`, the corresponding `SELECT` list will produce a row for each group in the result.  You're trying to take that result and aggregate twice, once with `GROUP BY [column_name_2]` and a second time with `GROUP BY ()`, as defined by standard SQL.  We can't do that in the same query expression.

The good news is you can break this up into more than one query expression:

```
WITH cte1 AS (
        SELECT count(distinct([column_name_1])) AS cnt
          FROM [table_name]
         GROUP BY [column_name_2]
     )
SELECT MAX(cnt) FROM cte1
;
```

or use a `derived table`.

You can even order the initial query result by `cnt DESC` and limit the result to the first row.

In your case, you may not want just the `MAX`, but also the other column.

With SQL Server, which you may be using.  Note: You should add a database specific tag to the question.

```
SELECT TOP 1 [column_name_2], count(distinct([column_name_1])) AS cnt
  FROM [table_name]
 GROUP BY [column_name_2]
 ORDER BY cnt DESC
;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand "this doesn't work", what were you expecting and what did you get? Normally you include the GROUP BY value in the result set. So it would be:

```
select [column_name_2], max(cnt) cnt 
    from (select [column_name_2], count(distinct [column_name_1]) cnt
          from [table_name]
          group by [column_name_2]) x
group by [column_name_2]
```

Ok, after reading your comment I think above is what you are looking for.

Comment: oh i am sorry about that, the error message is this: 
"Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery."
I am trying to know why. 

I am expecting to get the max count of distinct values in column_name_1 per unique column_name_2 value

Comment: Ok, changed my answer that should not have this error is SQL Server

Comment: @JBrooks I wrote mine out as you were changing yours. I will remove mine when I can. Update, I am currently unable to delete my answer. I will try when I am at a computer.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT [column_name_two]
    , max(x) x
FROM (
    SELECT [column_name_two]
        , COUNT(DISTINCT [column_name_one]
    FROM table_name
    GROUP BY [column_name_two]
) AS Tbl
GROUP BY [column_name_two]
```